# Fractional y-var in ggplot

Tags: r, graph

How can I easily create a fractional y-value when using ggplot?

```
t <- as.factor(test=sample(seq(0,100,10),1000,rep=T))
d <- as.factor(sample(c(0,1),1000,rep=T)
p <- data.frame(t,d)
```

My best shot was:

```
ggplot(p,aes(x=t,y=prop.table(table(t,d),1)[,1])) + geom_point()
```

However this doesnt work and I guess there is an easier way around this...

Comment: Isn't it January 2011? Why did this pop up to the top of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this should get you what you want using the formatFraction function from @jthetzel above

```
plotData <- data.frame(prop.table(table(t,d),1))

#Plot only non-zero values
plotData <- plotData[plotData$d == 1 , ]

ggplot(data = plotData, aes(x = t, y = Freq)) + geom_point() +
scale_y_continuous(formatter = "formatFraction")
```

Answer (score 1):

scale_y_continuous() accepts a 'formatter' argument which can take a function.  I was having some errors with your example code, but consider the following:

```
require(ggplot2)

t <- as.factor(sample(seq(0,100,10),1000,rep=T))
d <- as.factor(sample(c(0,1),1000,rep=T))
p <- data.frame(t,d)

formatFraction <- function(x)
{
    fraction <- paste(x*100, '/100', sep='')
    fraction
}


plot <- ggplot(p, aes(x=prop.table(table(t, d), 1)[,2], 
    y=prop.table(table(t, d), 1)[,1])) + geom_point()
plot + scale_y_continuous(formatter=formatFraction)
```

Comment: I would avoid naming an object `plot` as that may mask the `plot()` function in base R. Also, I don't think the OP wanted the x-axis transformed? It's a factor with 10 levels if I read it right.